# GatsbyJs gaphql query folder/post.md in graphiql interface

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I am using the Gatsby develop graphiql sandbox to test some queries, I have a working query that is pulling markdown files using the gatsby-transformer-remark plugin. My markdown files are located in `src/posts/post-1.md` these are returned in my query below, however I started to use Netlifys cms to create markdown files, and the way I set it up the markdown files are located in `src/team/post-1.md` Now this markdown file is not returned in the query, so it makes me think the default `allMarkdownRemark` query requires the markdown files to be in the `src/posts` folder is there a way to overwrite this and point to the `src/team` folder Ok that just about covers it here is my query.

```
query BlogPostArchive1 {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 10
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt
          frontmatter {
            title
            slug
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gatsby-transformer-remark` is a **transformer plugin**, which means that its only job is to parse and transform markdown.

Before it can do this, you need to tell it where to find the markdown files. This is where **source plugins** come in.

In your case, you are sourcing your markdown from within your filesystem (as opposed to an external source). The plugin you are looking for is `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

Since you used to be able to query markdown, you must already have `gatsby-source-filesystem` installed.

I think that the issue is the plugin's configuration: currently it is not looking into your `src/team/` directory.

Check your `gatsby-config.js` for code looking like this:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `posts`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/posts/`,
  },
},
```

Try to change the `path` line to:

```
    path: `${__dirname}/src/team/`,
```

Then make sure to rebuild your site.

Does it do the trick?

Comment: Im sure that is it makes sense, but now I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'allMarkdownRemark' of undefined` I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: When I change it back to `/posts` in my config file it starts working again. Hmmm

Comment: Do you mean run gatsby build, or is gatsby develop fine?

Comment: you would probably need to see all my queries that contain `allMarkDownRmark` should I try and comment all the sections that use that for now,  so I can get the graphiql editor open and test some new queries

Comment: You might have another setting somewhere pointing to `/posts`.

Comment: Is your site hosted on Github so that we could take a look? And yes I think that playing with Graphiql would help you debug it :)

Comment: It's on github here https://github.com/anderskitson/website-basics-gatsby it looks like the gatsby-node.js has a `path:` pointing to `/post/` but when I change it to `/team` it still has the same error. So close I think

Comment: Thanks! I tried to debug it but I couldn't find anything. I think the error happens when you [createPages](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages) in your `gatsby-node.js`, maybe you can take a look at the NodeAPI docs

Comment: Also make sure you add a `date` in your `team/` markdown files, otherwise you'll be trown errors later on (you're sorting the files by date in a query) :)